# calling Oracle Stored Procedure setup as Web Service

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net

I have a stored procedure written by someone.  The stored procedure is exposed as a web service.  The guts of the code is that it creates a custom array of a few fields selected and then returns it.

For better performance for internal systems integration I wish to call the stored procedure directly from .NET

However, I am unsure of the output types and whether the sizes need to be specified.

**Oracle Stored Procedure:**

```
opTradeListArray OSWTRADELISTARRAY; opTradeListArray(n) := WS_WSTRADELIST(T.XORCODE,T.XORDESC,t.XDAREF);
```

**Web Service:**

```
public class WS_WSTRADELIST : INullable, IOracleCustomType, IXmlSerializable
{
    private bool m_IsNull;
    private string m_OPWORKCENTRES;
    private string m_OPTRADECODE;
    private string m_OPTRADENAME;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(":1", OracleDbType.RefCursor, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "DB_INTEGRATION.BASE_GETTRADES_V1_0";
}
```

Does anyone have any examples?

Comment: Oracle Stored Procedure: opTradeListArray OSWTRADELISTARRAY;
opTradeListArray(n) := WS_WSTRADELIST(T.XORCODE,T.XORDESC,t.XDAREF);

Comment: Web Service:     public class WS_WSTRADELIST : INullable, IOracleCustomType, IXmlSerializable {
        
        private bool m_IsNull;
        
        private string m_OPWORKCENTRES;
        
        private string m_OPTRADECODE;
        
        private string m_OPTRADENAME;

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add(":1", OracleDbType.RefCursor, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "DB_INTEGRATION.BASE_GETTRADES_V1_0";

Comment: Want to do something like the above.